# Page Styling Is ignored

Tags: iis

I was asked to setup a test environment for a web app. I have set everything up on Windows Server 2022 in IIS that I can think of. Logging in worked fine. The landing page after logging in, seems to disregard all CSS styling. It is a Bootstrap site. This same code works in production.

Is there some other setting in IIS I am missing?

The errors I am seeing in the Console are mostly

'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT'

could this be caused by a slow server? Its a micro server so it does not have a lot of "meat" as they say.

Comment: There are many reasons for this error, If it is a timeout problem, then you can try the following method, right click on the site and go to Manage Web Site -> Advanced Settings. Under Connection Limits option, you should see Connection Time-out. If it doesn't work yet, please post the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

This issue came up when we were trying to set up a new test environment for our web app. That app has an SSL certificate.

What i failed to realize, some of the javascript and css files being called were to HTTPS. No bueno! nothing seemed to work. Adding an SSL certificate to that server for the new test site corrected the issue.